# Multi-View Form AngularJS reroute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been experimenting with a few ways to create this form. 
Scotch seemed to have a great tutorial with nested views.

This is the part of the JS file I assume the problems occur. 
I created a demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/nNTEI4tBw0XFana1nKIS?p=preview.

```
.controller('formController', function($scope) {

    // we will store all of our form data in this object
    $scope.formData = {};

    // function to process the form
    $scope.processForm = function() {
        if ($scope.formData = '"phone":"iphone' &&'"type":"xbox"'){
            parent.location='results';
        }
    };

});
```

How do I get the submit button to reroute to the results.html?
(I wouldn't be surprised if my JS was less than pristine)
any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that need to be done. First, if you examine your `$scope.formData` object, you can see that it has two properties for `phone` and `type`, so the way you were checking for that in the `if` block was not correct. Here are the controller changes:

```
.controller('formController', function($scope, $location) {

    // we will store all of our form data in this object
    $scope.formData = {};

    // function to process the form
    $scope.processForm = function() {

        if ($scope.formData.phone == 'iphone' && $scope.formData.type == 'xbox'){

            $location.path('/results');
        }
    };

});
```

Next, routes had to be configured for the `results` route. Just needed to add this in your route configuration:

```
.state('results', {
    url: '/results',
    templateUrl: 'results.html'
});
```

Here is a forked Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GUpNMRPU0YqfOcveB0nP?p=preview